# Why do I get the "can't read properties of null" error, when using "querySelectorAll.forEach"?

Tags: javascript, html, dry

Here is the code I have right now. Its purpose is to place an event listener on every button with the same class using `querySelectorAll` and some loop (currently using forEach), and make it a togglable "fav", toggling which will add or subtract 1 from the text in the `span` inside the button:

```js
const likeButtonArray = document.querySelectorAll('.likeButton');
const likeCountArray = document.querySelectorAll('.likeCount');
let likeButton = Array.from(likeButtonArray);
let likeCount = Array.from(likeCountArray);
// let count;
// [...likeButton].forEach((node) => console.log(node));
likeButton.forEach((like,index) => {
  /* Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
  at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>), at scr.js:3:12 */
  let count = parseInt(document.querySelector(`#likeCount:nth-of-type(${index+1})`).innerHTML);
  // let count = parseInt(document.querySelector(`like.firstElementChild`).innerHTML);
  // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML' at scr.js:4:84
  console.log(`assigned: ${index+1} ~ ${count}`)
  let counter = false;
  like.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter = !counter;
    if(counter) {
      console.log(`added for   ${index}`);
      count++;
      // like.classList.add('active');
      likeCount[index].innerHTML = toString(parseInt(like.innerHTML) + 1);
    } else {
      console.log(`removed for ${index}`);
      count--;
      // like.classList.remove('active');
      likeCount[index].innerHTML = toString(parseInt(like.innerHTML) - 1);
    }
    like.classList.toggle('active');
    console.log(`clicked:    ${index+1} ~ ${count}`)
    // likeCount[index].textContent = count.toString();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.likeButton {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.likeButton.active {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="likeButton">
  <span class="likeCount">69</span></button>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="likeButton">
  <span class="likeCount">420</span></button>
</div>
```

I had the `span` outside of the `button` earlier, but it has to be inside of it, so some JS is still leftover from the before. But, the code errors stayed the same:

```js
scr.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')
    at scr.js:5:84
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at scr.js:3:12
```

The code is not working, at all. Here is what is happening:

<s>The first button is the only one which has an event listener, all others do nothing when clicked.</s>

It's inner HTML is changed to "[objectUndefined]", and the class gets toggled.

I also get all the console logs that I placed.

EDIT: I decided to convert nodeLists to arrays by adding lines 3 and 4, and now nothing is working.

Why? How can I fix this, while keeping my code D.R.Y.?

Comment: IDs in HTML are meant to be unique, you have two elements with the same ID (**likeCount**).

Comment: @Titus Hm. I'll change them all to classes. Does that work?

Comment: instead of `document.querySelector(\`#likeCount:nth-of-type(${index+1})\`)`, you can use `like.firstElementChild`

Comment: instead of `forEach` use a simple `for` loop as using `forEach` on **nodelist** may not be supported on all browsers

Comment: @AniketPandey Can you answer with a way to do this with a `for` loop?

Comment: @Titus I also want to keep my code D.R.Y.

Comment: Why does the OP use the same `id` twice? ID's are unique in its usage. Why does the OP within the buttons' `forEach` query from `document` instead from the current button's parent element. Thus changing everywhere the `likeCount`-`id` to a `likeCount`-`className` and changing the overcomplicated query to ... `let count = parseInt(like.parentNode.querySelector('.likeCount').innerHTML);` already shows the correct log instead of error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really over complicating things. Select the buttons. Add a click listener to the button. Toggle the class. Select the element in the button that has the count and update the count based on the selection.

```js
const likeButtonArray = document.querySelectorAll('.likeButton');

likeButtonArray.forEach(button => {

  // add the click event to the button
  button.addEventListener("click", e => {

    // toggle the class
    button.classList.toggle("active");

    // Determine if active or not to do the calculation
    const dir = button.classList.contains("active") ? 1 : -1;

    // find the count holder in the button
    const countElem = button.querySelector(".likeCount");

    // update the count
    const likes = +countElem.textContent + dir;
    countElem.textContent = likes;
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.likeButton {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.likeButton.active {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="likeButton">
  <span class="likeCount">69</span></button>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="likeButton">
  <span class="likeCount">420</span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a regular old `for` loop as `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a **node-list** and `forEach` may not be supported on all browsers for **node-list**. Since `likeCount` will have the same index as `likeButton` , I have replaced the code for getting count by `let count = parseInt(likeCount[index].innerHTML);`. You also, don't need to use `toString` as `innerHTML` can take **number** and will parse automatically. the code is cleaner and more readable now.

```js
const likeButton = document.querySelectorAll('.likeButton');
const likeCount = document.querySelectorAll('#likeCount');
for (let index = 0; index < likeButton.length; index++) {
  const like = likeButton[index];
  let count = parseInt(likeCount[index].innerHTML);
  console.log(`assigned: ${index+1} ~ ${count}`)
  let counter = false;
  like.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter = !counter;
    if (counter) {
      count++;
      likeCount[index].innerHTML =(parseInt(likeCount[index].innerHTML) + 1);
    } else {
      count--;
      likeCount[index].innerHTML = parseInt(likeCount[index].innerHTML) - 1;
    }
    like.classList.toggle('active');
    
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.likeButton {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.likeButton.active {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="likeButton">
  <span id="likeCount">69</span></button>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="likeButton">
  <span id="likeCount">420</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: the innerhtml is set to [objectUndefined]. my console still says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML')
    at scr.js:5:41`, and nothing is working, at all.

Comment: Done, updated the answer check.

Comment: You were using `parseInt(like.innerHTML)` which will give you error because like has `<span>` inside it and that span contains the number. `like.innerHTML` will give you 
 "<span id="likeCount">420</span>", can not convert that to a number.

Comment: you had to put the console.log in the event listener. still nice code, though i alerady found the other answer working, and it looks cleaner.